# Keep watchers alive when component is inactive vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, keep-alive

I am using "keep-alive" with the expectation that i would still be able to execute my watchers when the component is inactive but this doesnt happen at all. I am able to take advantages of "deactivated()" and run an interval that continues to execute my calculation (which is normally done by the watcher when the component is active), but there has to be a different way?? I cannot get any use of "include" that doesnt not do anything if i try to capture my props in this way...
Example:

```
<transition>
 <keep-alive>
  <my-component :output="myOutput">
 </keep-alive>
</transition>
```

"myOutput" would be continuously changing data that updates my prop "output". output is watched within my component and executes a calc when it changes, that is only if the component is active. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use EventBus.